# Spring Integration - default exception channel implementation

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration. As part of one of my tasks, I am supposed to have a default error handling mechanism for any failure in the pipeline.

I have a file inbound channel adapter as a starting point which I has been written as follows:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inbound.jms.adapter" 
     directory="C:\Test
     channel="testChannel"
     auto-startup="false">
     <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" error-channel="default-error-channel" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The channel will be used further by different components.

My question is, in case of any failure further, will the exception fallback to default error channel?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, in case of any failure further, will the exception fallback to default error channel?

No, not fully. If your downstream is `direct` (composed only with `DirectChannel`s), then yes: all exceptions will be thrown to that `default-error-channel` on this first polling channel adapter.

But if transfer you message to different channels (`QueueChannel`, `ExecutorChannel`) the exception will be handled via their mechanism. In most cases it is default `errorChannel` from the Spring Integration.

See more info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler).

In addition there is `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with the exception handling feature for the particular endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Artem.
Am I correct in assuming that by having a service activator to 'erorChannel' will provide a global catch block of any exception that happens in the application.

Comment: True. But as I said: it will work until you don't transfer message to the non-direct channel. It works here like `try...catch` in pure Java: if you start a new Thread within that block, its exceptions won't be available for your root `try...catch`

Comment: Ok. Thank you. If I am passing the message to non-direct channels, I would then need to explicitly mentione error-channel. Am I correct?
I have something like th

Comment: Ok. Thank you. If I am passing the message to non-direct channels, I would then need to explicitly mentione error-channel. Am I correct? I have something like this at the moment


 <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inbound.jms.adapter" 
  directory="C:\Test"
  channel="inbound.jms.channel"
  >
  <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" error-channel="default-error-channel" />
 </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
 
 <int:channel id="inbound.jms.channel"/>
 <int:channel id="default-error-channel"/>

Comment: <int:service-activator input-channel="inbound.jms.channel" ref="defaultExeptionHandler" method="handleException"/>
 <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="defaultExeptionHandler" method="handleGlobalException"/>
 
 <bean id="defaultExeptionHandler" class="com.hsbcib.janus.tradeloader.exception.DefaultExceptionHandler"/>

The service activator on inbound.jms.channel throws an exception which I hoping will be caught in the service activator on errorChannel. But it is not happening.

Why is it not falling to global errorChannel?

Comment: Please, edit your question for better readability. You can try to use `error-channel` header for the message. And framework uses `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` to determine the target `channel` in particular case.

Comment: Apologies for edit issue.
So if I enrich my messge with error-channel, this enrichment will flow thoughout the application and Sping in case of any exception will put the exception on this error-channel.  Having service activator on this channel, I can then read the exceptions and do what ever I want to. Am I correct please?

Comment: Right. But it doesn't work for all cases. E.g. `<gateway>` does that with a bit different way. From other side be sure that your `errorHandler` `<service-activator>` is listening to your appropriate error channel, not the default `errorChannel`.